# How to perform a Distinct on EntityObject List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

Distinct() can't be apply on some Entities cause some fields can't be hashed (as text field).

Answer (score 1):

After all when Distinct is needed on an EntityObject we only need comparison to be made on the entity key. 
IEqualityComparer can be implemented like so :

```
public class EntityObComparer : IEqualityComparer<EntityObject>
{
    public bool Equals(EntityObject x, EntityObject y)
    {
        return x.EntityKey.Equals(y.EntityKey);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(EntityObject obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then distinct can be perform like so :

```
var foo = MyListOfEntityObjects.Distinct(new EntityObComparer());
```